# How can I get the parent of a FrameworkElement in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am writing a C# XAML Windows Store app. I have a grid on my page. I add a child element to that grid and I immediately try to get the parent of this child. The parent is null. There does not seem to be a way to get the parent grid from the child element. Here's some code to show what I'm doing. It's not all that complicated:

This is the code that adds the child element and tries to get the parent element:

```
FrameworkElement FieldView = Field.getView( true );
ContentPanel.Children.Add( FieldView );
Panel theParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(FieldView) as Panel;
FrameworkElement theotherparent = (FrameworkElement)FieldView.Parent;
```

ContentPanel is a Grid on the page. FieldView is a UserControl. The page displays just fine and there are no exceptions in any of the code. The only thing that is wrong is that I cannot get the parent of FieldView. It is null.

Before posting this, I did a quick test to make sure that UserControl was not the issue. using a TextBlock shows the same problem:

```
TextBlock Derf = new TextBlock();
PageGroup.ContentPanel.Children.Add(Derf);
Panel theParent2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(Derf) as Panel;
FrameworkElement theotherparent2 = (FrameworkElement)Derf.Parent;
```

Does the parent property never get set in a Windows Store app? This code worked fine on Window Phone 8.

Thanks for any help.

Dave

Comment: Try making sure that the `Panel` is `Loaded` before trying to get the `Parent`. You can do this by adding your logic to the `Loaded` event.

Comment: Thanks. I found this problem because of code I wrote that tries to remove the child from the parent when I leave the page (in the OnNavigatingFrom event). The page was visible and working before the failure. I will try your suggestion to confirm that it never works.

Comment: One other thing to check is that the `GetParent` call is `null` before casting to `Panel`.

Comment: Is it appropriate for you to post your "use Loaded event" comment as the answer or for me to post your comment as the answer? You were absolutely right. I'm still learning the quirks of the Windows Store App API. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Nate suggested, adding child elements to a Grid works as expected when it is done within the "Loaded" event handler. It only fails within the "OnNavigatedTo" handler. Changing the place in the code where I add the children lets me get a non-null parent.

I would like to point out that this is a bit strange (like a bug). The Grid object exists, so it doesn't make sense that it cannot be set as the parent of the child object. Additionally, even if the parent property is set to null, the code somehow knows that there is a parent object/container because it throws an exception if I try to add the child to more than one Grid.